# Need advice on 3D and 2D C++ framework selection

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, ogre, ogre3d

We are a small company with only 2 programmers. We currently make small 2D and 3D games for desktop and mobile using Adobe Flash/Air. We want to stop using that framework and start learning and developing on C++ because there are much more and better libraries and frameworks available on C++.

I'm not sure about the libraries to use for rendering. I know that Ogre3D is a great rendering engine for 3D content but sometimes we need to make 2D games or "2.5D" games, sometimes with video playback, and all that need to be mixed with 3D scenes.

I know there are 2D frameworks like cocos2D-x and smfl that works with OpenGL (I don't know much about OpenGL) and can do all the 2D things I need, but can those frameworks be combined with Ogre3D? And can it be done without the need of knowing how all the Ogre3D internal stuff or OpenGL works?

If Ogre3D can be combined with any 2D engine, what do I need to learn to merge the frameworks?

Comment: any reason you don't just use unity?

Comment: You can do 2D in ogre.  Don't forget that 2D is just a plane in 3D.

Comment: Why do you need to combine 2D engine with 3D one? I think that game can be either 2D *or* 3D, so no reason to combine. Or not? Also, in my opinion, SFML is pretty good for 2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have been using flash, I am guessing you are not porting old C++ code.

Also, since you don't want to know about how the internals of the framework you're using or how OpenGL actually works, you don't need a low level language like C++.

An abundance of open source libraries is not a very good reason to program your game in C++ either.

[**Unity3D**](http://www.unity3d.com/) has a free basic license, and provides everything you need out of the box.

For now, you can use planes with textures to do your 2D work, but Unity will also be coming out with a set of [**Native 2D Tools**](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/08/28/unity-native-2d-tools/) in the near future. Also, a [**new GUI system**](http://video.unity3d.com/video/6943180/unite-2012-using-the-new-gui) is being created.

For any C++ library you think you may need, there is probably something already built into unity that does what you want. If there isn't, there is probably a .NET port that you can use. And if all else fails, you can write a C interface for any library you need, and use it as a plugin in Unity.

One big problem with Unity though, is that you need Unity Pro to use plugins. Unity licenses are per-platform, So if you decide to use plugins, and release your game for multiple platforms, you could end up paying a lot of money in [**licensing fees**](https://store.unity3d.com/).

Finally, it's not just an application framework you'll need. You'll also need a level editor. Building a 3D level editor is not a trivial task, and given that your team consists of only two people, this fact alone should be enough to seriously consider using Unity.

So unless you are porting old code, need low level access to hardware, or have specific needs for native code, my advice is **don't use C++**, just use **Unity**.

Comment: First of all, the next release is Unreal engine 4, not 2. Second, if all you want is to learn C++, it doesn't matter which framework you use. All of them have advantages and disadvantages. And since something as important as wanting to use OpenCV was left out of your original question, you are either purposely omitting important details, or don't really know what you want. Both of those cases prevent anyone from giving you any real meaningful answer to your question.

Comment: Not really off topic. You asked for advice, and this is mine. I too, prefer C++, but given your goal, which seems very ambitious for a team of two, C++ is probably not the best option. But if you still insist on using C++, you should edit your original post with more specific details of exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ogre3D can handle such "2D tasks" as playing a video. Simply a plane in 3D space that it gets projected onto. However for pure 2D projects an 3D rendering engine such as Ogre3D is usually overkill. If you are talking about 2,5D though, you are back in play with Ogre3D.

Regarding integrations: Not completely sure, but I guess those other 2D frameworks need an OpenGL rendering context that you can get from Ogre.

**EDIT:** [Same question](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=79163&) has been asked in the official Ogre3D forums.

Answer (score -1):

We are another small team working on game development.

We tried many rendering engines and finally settled down with Irrlicht Rendering engine. Irrlicht is no way better than Ogre 3D or am not trying to prove that. We felt Irrlicht more flexible for our need. It also supports 2D rendering and it is quite fast with batching. Irrlicht can be easily ported to other platforms, It took us a week to port it to Google Chrome NaCl.

Irrlicht is a very basic rendering system that supports OpenGL and OpenGL ES, so its easy for your to go mobile. You can add any advanced features without much effort. Some of our games are available for iOS, Android, Windows PC, Mac OSX, Linux and Google Chrome Native Client.

Comment: Since I am working with Ogre3D, some quick comments: Ogre3D is also available for many platforms including a NaCl port. Same applies for OpenGL and OpenGL ES (so iOS, Android, WP8 all there as well). Bottom-line: In regards to cross-platform support, Irrlicht and Ogre3D are quite similar.

Comment: The only reason we chose against Ogre3d, is because its quite advanced compared to Irrlicht. Ogre3d has advanced features like Mesh Batching, Instancing all implemented in the core. However, Irrlicht also has these features with some changes from the community. this gives us the flexibility. It all depends on your need. If you are trying to learn stuff before adding it, you can choose Irrlicht, on the other side, Ogre3d has everything ready for you.